# Spyder IDE: Modify source code on server

Tags: python, spyder

Can I use Spyder IDE to modify python source code which resides on server? I can't seem to find that functionality. 
Please help me, thank you very much.

Comment: May you be more specific what do you mean by "resides on server"?

Comment: @abukaj Suppose I have a python source file on server. With Visual studio code, when I connect to server using Sftp (using Ubuntu's "connect to server" functionality) I can immediately access files on server. I'm wondering if I can do the same with Spyder. I really want do away with Studio code if possible :)

Comment: Have you tried to open a remote file with Spyder (from context menu of your file manager)? (I have no experience with "connect to server", but that is the first thing I'd try).

Comment: @abukaj I don't understand what you're talking about. I tried /open but there is no server location :(

Comment: I mean https://askubuntu.com/questions/349873/use-connect-to-server-to-connect-to-sftp#349879

Comment: You can also use `sshfs` to mount your remote server as a local file system.